# How to setup fullcone NAT on linux router?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, nat

The current version of iptables only supports snat and dnat.  Which type of NAT are they using?  Fullcone NAT, Restricted Cone NAT, Port Restricted Cone NAT or Symmetric NAT?  How can I tell iptables to use fullcone nat?

Comment: I have seen 'fullcone' is somewhat commonly implemented as a 1-to-1 mapping that is a combination of a SNAT and DNAT rule that maps 1 public IP exclusively to 1 private IP.  Though as @poige there isn't 100% agreement about the usage of that term, or how it is used/implemented in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

As RFC4787 states: "…

STUN [RFC3489] used the terms "Full Cone", "Restricted Cone", "Port
Restricted Cone", and "Symmetric" to refer to different variations of
NATs applicable to UDP only.  [Unfortunately, this terminology has
been the source of much confusion, as it has proven inadequate at
describing real-life NAT behavior](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4787).  This specification therefore
refers to specific individual NAT behaviors instead of using the
Cone/Symmetric terminology.

…"

> How can I tell iptables to use fullcone nat?

Taking into consideration the quote above, it makes sense instead to ask what exact behaviour are you expecting to get from Linux' NAT and are you sure it's not supporting it by default? I'll update the answer accordingly.